# Bootstrap Calander inside table cell over flow

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to append date time picker (bootstrap calander)inside table cell but it's not working properly. calender appear but table cell of bootstrap calendar is overflowed. Can anyone have solution?I've loaded the form dynamically.
//html code

```
<div class="input-group date form_datetime" onclick='GetDate(this.id);'id="orgfromdatepicker">
  <input id="orgFromDate" type="text" size="16" readonly="true" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span> 
</div>
```

//js code

```
function GetDate(id) {
  $('#' + id).datetimepicker({ format: "YYYY-MM-DD ", ignoreReadonly: true });
}
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Can you post a code snippet or upload a snapshoot?

Comment: @TTCC i've reedited the question.

Comment: I'm not sure which datetimepicker plugin you are using. Can u post a url of its official website?

Comment: @TTCC i've also used the same plugin in another page but it works fine but here it shows the problem because i've place the above code inside table td element.....

Comment: Maybe there are some conflict styles.